# Strip specific tag from parent (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, tags, strip

HTML:

```
<div class="featured">
    <h4><a href="#">Title 1</a></h4>
    <a href="#"><img src="image.png" class="image"/></a>
    <p><a href="#"></a><br />
    Description goes here</p>
</div>

<div class="featured">
    <h4><a href="#">Title 2</a></h4>
    <a href="#"><img src="image.png" class="image"/></a>
    <p><a href="#"></a></p>
    <p>Description goes here</p>
</div>
```

.. How do I strip out all `<p>` tags from .featured?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but only because your paragraph elements are at the end of your divs:

```
$(".featured p").each(function(){
    var content = $(this).html();
    $(this).parent().append(content);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: `.text()` won't return you children tags.

Comment: @Adam Kiss - true, changed it to html() instead. Not sure if that warranted a down-vote though :)

Comment: Deleted downvote - it does not work :) Now it does - but look at my (edited) code though :) tested, does not `append()`, but `after()`, so it's in place of deleted `<p>`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Ben Alman's unwrap "plugin"](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-unwrap-plugin/)

```
$.fn.unwrap = function() {
  this.parent(':not(body)')
    .each(function(){
      $(this).replaceWith( this.childNodes );
    });

  return this;
};
```

your usage would be:

```
$(".featured p > *").unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".featured p").remove();
```

This works by changing each `<p>` to `<span>`. It does that in-place, so the `<p>`s don't have to be at the end (no append - it will not reorder the elements):

```
$(".featured p").replaceWith(function(){
     return $('<span />').html( $(this).html() );
});
```

It is using html, so the element will lose data and event bindings.

Comment: But this way, you'll delete also it's contents, as I understand it, he wants just to strip the tags out.

Comment: exactly. I want to strip the tags only, not content.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$(".featured p").each(
  function(){
    $(this).after($(this).html()).remove();
});
```

Edit 2: Tested, works. nice and simple.

Comment: Well, it was written just as an idea, not solution, i haven't tested it.

Comment: I still think this is closest to requirements :P No spans included, tested(finally), just strips out wrapper (in this case `<p>`) :]

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery 1.4 you could do it like this:

```
$(".featured p *").unwrap();
$(".featured p").each(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith("<span>"+ $(this).text() + "</span>")
});
```

Test it [here](http://jsbin.com/axuso/edit)

Text nodes don't get unwraped, so you have to do them separately. I'm not sure why replaceWith requires them to be inside tags.